# OkHttp not multiplexing SPDY connections on Android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, okhttp, spdy

I am trying to do some experiment on Android and SPDY using OkHttp. However, I cannot get the multiplex feature of SPDY work on my Android phone. Below is my code.

```
private static final long WAIT_TIME = 1000 * 2; // Wait 2 seconds between each connection.
private static final long SIZE = 1000 * 1000 * 5; // Size of the content requested.

private static final String LOC = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

private final static OkHttpClient mClient;
private final static OkUrlFactory mFactory;

static {
    mClient = new OkHttpClient();
    mClient.setConnectTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mClient.setFollowRedirects(false);
    mClient.setFollowSslRedirects(false);
    mClient.setProxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    //mClient.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(false);
    mFactory = new OkUrlFactory(mClient);
}

private void startOkHttp() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int idx = i;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(idx);
                try {
                    testOkHttpClient(LOC + "/" + idx);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        thread.start();
    }
}

private void testOkHttpClient(String fileLoc) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Multiplexing connections: " + ConnectionPool.getDefault().getMultiplexedConnectionCount());
    System.out.println("getConnectionCount: " + ConnectionPool.getDefault().getConnectionCount());
    System.out.println("getHttpConnectionCount: " + ConnectionPool.getDefault().getHttpConnectionCount());
    System.out.println("getSpdyConnectionCount: " + ConnectionPool.getDefault().getSpdyConnectionCount());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://the same url for all the connections")
            .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
            .addHeader("User-Agent", "com.google.android.youtube/10.05.6(Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en_US; Nexus 5 Build/KOT49H)")
            .addHeader("Range", "bytes=0-" + SIZE)
            .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
            .build();

    Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute();

    System.out.println("Status: " + response.code());

    InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();
    File file = new File(fileLoc);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ChannelUtils.fastChannelCopy(is, fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

Basically it initiates a HTTP GET method to the same url (a video) every 2 seconds. What I was expecting was **a single HTTPS connection and all 10 connections were multiplexed in it**. However, what I found using wireshark is that there are 10 connections going to the same IP address. <s>The good thing is that Wireshark tells me that **each connections are using SPDY**.</s>

<s>Wireshark output:</s>

<s>TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: spdy</s>

The HTTPS connections are not reused since all connections started before any one finished downloading, which is reasonable.

The other thing is all the `getMultiplexedConnectionCount()`, `getConnectionCount()`, `getHttpConnectionCount()`, `getSpdyConnectionCount()` are giving me `0`. I am so confused about it.
As I read on the main page of okhttp, it should support SPDY with multiplexing. Could anyone tell me what I did wrong with the code? Or anyone can point out any other lib that I can use to do SPDY multiplexing on Android?

Thank you all for reading this!

**Update**:
I am using a Android phone with Android 4.4.2, okhttp-2.2.0.

**Update 2**
`response.protocol()` returns me `http/1.1`, which is different from what I found in wireshark.

**Follow up question:**

With the above code, I successfully connect to `https://www.google.ca` and get `spdy/3.1` with `response.protocol()`, which shows alpn is working fine. However when I tried to connect to http/2 enabled sites like `https://h2duo.trafficmanager.net/` (it is a public http/2 test website), I am always getting `http/1.1`, not `http/2` or something using the above code. In chrome, I can see that `h2duo.cloudapp.net:443` with `Protocol Negotiated:h2-14`. I can see from okhttp code that I have `h2-16` as one of the output of `(OkHttpClient)mClient.getProtocols()`.

So why can't I connect to `https://h2duo.trafficmanager.net/` with `http/2`?

Comment: What do you get in response.protocol() ? http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Response.html#protocol--

Comment: I am getting `http/1.1`. It surprises me that it is not the same result I got with wireshark. Any idea about that? @Gorcyn

Comment: Can you try on `https://www.google.com` ? On my side, I got "spdy/3.1". If you don't get the same, it would be a *strange* device problem. If you get it, you would check if server's SPDY implementation it ok. (https://spdycheck.org/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried `https://www.google.com` and get `spdy/3.1`! So there is nothing wrong with the client. It should be something wrong with the server. I was trying to get some resource from a server hosted by google. As the initiator of SPDY, I cannot imagine they do not support SPDY now. How weird!

Comment: It's most likely a problem with NPN and ALPN. We dropped NPN in OkHttp 2.2. That was premature, and we're going to put it back in 2.3. That'll negotiate more SPDY connections more successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your information, Jesse! But I am sorry to disturb again, could anyone tell me why can't I have http/2 work as stated in my "Follow up question"? @JesseWilson

Comment: I think they support draft 14, but we support draft 16. Don't worry; soon we'll all be on the final HTTP/2.